# Cake php with Extjs Through editable grid update,insert and delete

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, extjs, integration

I want to develop cake php with extjs 3.2 through editable grid.

in grid we can insert and update and delete operation.

when we get data from "movie" model file and create one json file in view/movie/json

in json file i got data but

if i want to show data in grid then this json file data how can i take in grid store.

Thankyou.

Comment: You should try and do a little research on your own before coming here and asking, if you do not know how it works look for the API and tutorials and then come with specific questions. This is the CakePHP cookbook, it has a couple of tutorials and explains everything you need to know http://book.cakephp.org/ also if your question is closed for not being good don't reopen the same question again.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

At work we do extensive work with CakePHP and ExtJS.

Our views that use ExtJS alone only have calls to include the specific javascript file for that view, and one div to render the ExtJS module to.

If you are using `<?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?>` in the head of your layout you can easily append single javascript files *from inside* your view using

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('relative/path/from/js/folder.js', array('inline' => false)) ?>
```

In Ext, you'll want to set up your grid to use an instance of `Ext.data.Store`, through the store and it's dependencies (you'll also need a proxy, reader, and writer) you can send data back and forth to your CakePHP controllers.

We prefer to use JSON for our data as it's easy to manipulate and persist where we need it.

Our basic setup usually looks like this.

In ExtJS

```
var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    api: {
        // these will map to cakephp controller actions
        create:  { url: '/cake_controller/create',  method: 'POST' },
        read:    { url: '/cake_controller/read',    method: 'GET'  },
        update:  { url: '/cake_controller/update',  method: 'POST' },
        destroy: { url: '/cake_controller/destroy', method: 'POST' }
    }
});

var fields = Ext.data.Record.create([
    // this will map to your database fields (or at least the ones your
    // returning from cakephp to put in your grid
    { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'another_model_field' },
    { name: 'created', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s' },
    { name: 'modified', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s' },
]);

var reader = Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'controllerName' // this is the root node of the json cakephp is replying with
}, fields);

var writer = Ext.data.JsonWriter({
    encoded: true,
    writeAllFields: true
});

var store = Ext.data.Store({
    storeId: 'myStore',
    proxy: proxy,
    reader: reader,
    writer: writer,
    autoSave: true,
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Then inside your grid, set your store to the one you've just created

```
var grid = Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Any time the store is changed, it will call the related api method (create, read, update, destroy) which is mapped to your CakePHP controller actions. Inside your actions you can access the data via `$this->params['form']`. If you use Json, like we do you can decode that into an associative array using `json_decode($this->params['form'], true)` for easy manipulation/persistence on the CakePHP side of things.

You can return certain things from your CakePHP actions so ExtJS knows whether the save/update/etc was successful. We usually just return `array('success' => true)` encoded in Json.

I hope this helps you get started, it's a lot to take in but it's not a ton of work just a lot of typing. It's easy to remember once you've done it a few times.

Whenever you're working with ExtJS, remember the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) are your friend!

Comment: thanks Brandon Cordell,  I try with API object but its not shown data in grid. First i create on controller file "movie_controller" then after in view/Folder/ create one CTP file "read", then in JS API object i write down                                          read:    { url: '/movie_controller/read',    method: 'GET'  },